# Does AnyTree support multiple nodes with same name in different hierarchies?

Tags: duplicates, treenode, anytree

I am trying to create a tree with a node that can appear in more than 1 hierarchies.

Example:
   `A --> B ; A --> C ; A --> D --> C`
Alternatively, I can think of them as separate nodes but 'C' under 'A' and 'C' under 'D' will need to have the same name. Is this supported in anyTree?

Find function fails because it is reporting two hierarchies.

Comment: Having different hierarchies violates the tree structure, what you’re thinking of is more similar to a DAG (directed acyclic graph) structure.